# How does e.g. TextWrangler generates the preview in finder?

Tags: cocoa, swift, quicklook

i am almost done with my application. The user is able to edit special files. Now i want to provide a Finder preview but i get stuck.

I watched the apple video about Quick Lock but i am confused.

TextWrangler for example has a scrolable view of the file content. That is what i want for my Documents.

Can you give me a hint how to do this?
[image]

My knowledge so far is that i have to write a QuickLock Plugin. The XCode template is wirtten in c, so i suggest i have to use c, not swift. 
If I am right two questions: 
- How do i get a scrolled view with text content form a file
- How to put the .qlgenerator inside my main project's Contents/Library/.. folder?

Thanks a lot for any help. Two days reading is not always the way to get clear about things.

*** Update **
this is my info.plist CFBundleDocumentTypes

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>json</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>Icon_512x512@2x</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>JSON Document</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeOSTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>TEXT</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.json</string>
            <string>public.text</string>
            <string>public.data</string>
            <string>public.item</string>
            <string>public.content</string>
        </array>
        <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).Document</string>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.json</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>JSON source file</string>
        <key>UTTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>Icon_512x512@2x</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>public.json</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>json</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UTImportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.json</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>JSON source file</string>
        <key>UTTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>Icon_512x512@2x</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>public.json</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>json</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

But this is still the preview without preview text or even an icon:
[image]

Comment: It depends partly on the UTI

Comment: .js would be interpreted as a JavaScript file which the OS already knows about and probably defaults to using a QL renderer for plain text.

Comment: Do i have to say it in my main application? Can i say that my application is handled plain text files?

Comment: Generally it's just an addition to the Info.plist but Xcode has a UI for this. Take a look at the document based app programming guide as well as the TextEdit sample code. Then look at TextWrangler's Info.plist or any other app.

Comment: You'd probably have to write your own QuickLook plugin and have your app install it into the correct location (`/Library/QuickLook/`) if it's not already installed there for the user.  (Depending on what kind of preview you want)

Comment: Is your document type a specialization of plain text? That is, could a plain text viewer or editor show your document's contents? If so, then your document type UTI should declare conformance to `public.plain-text` or one of the types that descends from it. If it does, you should get what you want for free.

Comment: Hi Ken, yes plaintext is what I want. Where to declare the conformance? Thank you a lot of times!

Comment: I added my plist and a scennshot. There is no preview and even not the app icon. But the App ist known as preferred Application and will be open on dbclick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your app just works with JSON files. That is, they are not some specialization of JSON files.

Therefore, you should not attempt to export any UTI. You are using a system-defined UTI, and you should not export those. You just import them. (Exporting a UTI means that you are attempting to define the UTI. It's not about what types of files your app can write/save.)

Then, in your `LSItemContentTypes` array, just list `public.json`. Your app can't open *arbitrary* text, data, or content. It can only open JSON data. So, just list that.

Unfortunately, `public.json` conforms to `public.text` and not `public.plain-text` and it seems the system doesn't provide a QuickLook preview for that. So, you don't get for free with your documents.

What you could do is export a new UTI which conforms to both `public.json` and `public.plain-text`. Your new UTI should use a different file extension to distinguish it from the system-defined `public.json`'s extension. Then, add a dictionary to `CFBundleDocumentTypes` with the specifics for your unique document type. That way, your app will still be able to import .json files as well as your custom document type. I would expect that only your custom type would get QuickLook previews.

For example, you'd put this in the `UTExportedTypeDeclarations` array:

```
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.json</string>
            <string>public.plain-text</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>Your Document Type Description</string>
        <key>UTTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>Icon_512x512@2x</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.yourcompany.yourapp.yourdocumenttypename</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>yourdocumentextension</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

You'll have to fill in various placeholders that I put in there, since I don't know what good values would be. You would invent a filename extension that makes sense for your app. Likewise, you would invent a UTI based on the reverse domain name of your company, similar to your bundle identifier.

Then, you would add this to the `CFBundleDocumentTypes` array as the first element:

```
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>yourdocumentextension</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>Icon_512x512@2x</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Your Document Type Description</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.yourcompany.yourapp.yourdocumenttypename</string>
        </array>
        <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).Document</string>
    </dict>
```

Obviously, you'll need to fill in the placeholders again.

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for this explanation. I understand the first part, and fixed it. The second part i understand in theory, but have issues in praxis. Do you have the time to give me an example. I's very hard to get it right, with my level of knowledge.

Comment: I have added some example Info.plist entries to my answer.